# Create a method that creates a new array based on the values ​passed

Tags: javascript

What is the best way to implement a method that creates a new array based on the values ​​passed.
Method entries (3, a),
Method result: ['a', 'a', 'a']

It's a question of an exercise, but I wasn't able to interpret the question.

I was trying this:

```js
const arr = [];
arr.push(3, 'a');

console.log(arr);
```

Comment: There is no best way. There are many ways to do that. It would be nice if you share what you have done so far with us.

Comment: @Matheus Rodrigues Answer see below. What do you need the function for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Very simple Funktion. Just a FOR loop and then array push() function.

```js
function makeArray(num, val) {
    const newArray= [];
  for (let i = 0; i < num; i++) {
    newArray.push(val);
  }
  return newArray;
}

const result = makeArray(3,'a');
console.log(result)
```

Comment: Thanks for helping, I had forgotten to send what I had tried (I edited the question).